# YamlPropertySourceFactory fails to load 'S&P', and instead loads 'SP'

Tags: snakeyaml, spring-boot-3, java-21

I am using Spring Boot 3.2 with Java 21, along with SnakeYAML 2.2.

I am trying to load yaml file *sources.yaml*. This is how my YAML looks like:

```
sources:
    "S&P":
        cron: '0 30 1 * * SUN-SAT'
        calculateCA: 'true'
        modifyOhlc: 'true'
```

And this is how SourcesConfig class looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
@Slf4j
@PropertySource(value = "file:config/sources.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class SourcesConfig2 {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Map<String, MetaData> sources;

    @Data
    public static class MetaData {
        private String cron;
        private boolean calculateCA;
        private boolean modifyOhlc;
        private String lastUpdatedTime;
        private ZoneOffset gmtOffset;
    }
}

public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();
        String fileName = encodedResource.getResource().getFilename();

        Objects.requireNonNull(fileName);
        Objects.requireNonNull(properties);
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(fileName, properties);
    }
}
```

I have removed other methods for brevity. At initial loadup, I have noticed an error popping up and went to debug. S&P is loaded as SP.
[image]

While debugging I noticed that the file is correctly loading. Something changed after its loadup and I cannot pinpoint what went wrong exactly.
[image]

What is wrong here? I have tried with other combinations like 'S$P', 'S@P' etc. and for some reason any special character is missed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are running into [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13404). You need to surround the `S&P` config/map key with square brackets as suggested [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13404#issuecomment-395307439), so that the key becomes `"[S&P]"` from `"S&P"`